# Why wont my bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown menu work?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, navbar

I can't seem to figure it out. jQuery is referenced before the bootstrap javascript, the html code seems fine too. Any ideas?

Nav:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <img src="<?php $BASEURL;?>assets/img/logo.png" alt="CraftZealous"/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-info" href="<?php echo $BASEURL; ?>" style="font-weight: 700;">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="<?php echo $BASEURL;?>faq">HELP &amp; FAQ</a>    
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="<?php echo $BASEURL;?>community">COMMUNITY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">NEWS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <?php if ($session->isAdmin()) { echo '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-warning" href="admin/admin.php">ADMINCP</a></li>';} ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-danger" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-transform:uppercase;">SC</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account settings</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="process.php">Log out &raquo;</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

javascript reference at bottom of file before :

```
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what says the console debug ?

Comment: you hate answering ?

Answer (score -1):

Your snippet is a PHP script; you should debug the resulting HTML, not the code with PHP inclusions.

After PHP parts are removed and Bootstrap 4 CSS file is included in the page HEAD section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

your page totally works.

[image: menu]

Final working HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="CraftZealous"/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-info" href="#" style="font-weight: 700;">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#faq">HELP &amp; FAQ</a>    
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#community">COMMUNITY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">NEWS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-danger" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-transform:uppercase;">SC</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account settings</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="process.php">Log out &raquo;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```